# TFS 2012 - Is there place to save list of test scenarios for a specific page?

Tags: testing

I am not familiar with TFS testing. 
I have googled many Testing scenarios with TFS 2012, but what I'm looking for is to, in TFS, save a list of test scenarios that the Testers have to go through for a specific page.

The idea is to keep it centralized on TFS so that it does not get lost in an email or is difficult to find if we keep it in a Word Document on a server somewhere.

E.g.

```
Placing Order
1. Check order qty between parameters A and B
2. Check non-numeric quantities are not allowed
3. Check negative quantities are not allowed
```

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is manual testing in Microsoft Test Manager. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd286599.aspx

In TFS they are called Test Cases, not Scenarios. That should help your googling efforts.